# Trigger change field when it's null

Tags: postgresql, triggers

i'm trying to create a trigger that add a determined value to a field when the user doesn't add a value to it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fAsignaDepartament()
returns trigger as $$

    begin               
        NEW.deptno = (select deptno from dept where lower(dname)='SALES');      
        return null;    
    end;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER tAsignaDepartament
    BEFORE INSERT ON emp
    FOR EACH ROW
    WHEN (NEW.deptno is null)
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE fAsignaDepartament();
```

But the result is that i can' seem to do inserts anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If everyone is interested the answer was to change the fuction return to new.